# Python prints { } instead of an empty space - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

In this simple example, I would like the label to be displayed as "1   3":

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

A = [1," ", 3]

label = tkinter.Label(window, text = A[0:])
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

However, python displays "1 { } 3" instead.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why didn't you get "[1, ' ', 3]"?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: because underlying tkinter is a tcl interpreter, and tcl treats lists differently than python. The curly braces are a sign that what you're seeing is the tcl representation of a list converted to a string, where the conversion was done by tcl rather than python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonathan and Ron Norris already said, you need to pass a string to the `text` argument of the `Label` constructor.

I would suggest to transform your heterogeneous list to a string thusly:

```
A = [1," ", 3]
labeltext = ''.join(map(str, A))
label = tkinter.Label(window, text = labeltext)
```

- Documentation link for `map`: [map documentation for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- Documentation for `str`: [str documentation for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)
- Documentation for the `join` method of `string`: [string join method, python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

**Edit:** Since you now ask for a way to do this in many code locations, with minimal code changes, I would suggest this wrapper around `tkinter.Label`:

```
def createlabel(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'text' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['text'], list):
        kwargs['text'] = ''.join(map(str, kwargs['text']))
    return tkinter.Label(*args, **kwargs)
```

This function will pass all of its arguments unchanged to `tkinter.Label`, but taking care to transform a `text` keyword argument to a string, if it is a list.

When you have defined this, use a "Find & Replace" function in your editor to replace calls to `tkinter.Label` with `createlabel`.

Your original could would be transformed like this, for example:

```
import tkinter

def createlabel(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'text' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['text'], list):
        kwargs['text'] = ''.join(map(str, kwargs['text']))
    return tkinter.Label(*args, **kwargs)

window = tkinter.Tk()

A = [1," ", 3]

label = createlabel(window, text = A[0:])
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As I have commented above, in the original program, I actually have 71 different lists and labels... is there an alternative in which I would not need to this 71 times?

Comment: @JindraKocman I edited by answer to provide a way to do this easily in a lot of code locations (by using a function and Find&Replace)

Answer (score 1):

`A[0:]` is a heterogeneous list, tkinter.Label's documentation suggests that its `text` parameter should receive a string (Which the word "text" also quite strongly suggests)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#label-options

Answer (score 1):

If you *want* "1 3", try:

```
A = [1," ", 3]
s = ''
for c in A:
    s += str(c)

label = tkinter.Label(window, text = s)
```

Comment: That works, however, in my original program I have 71 list which are displayed in 71 labels and writing this 71 times would be a pain in the ... is there an alternative?

Comment: You make repetitive operations into functions. So when you create the labels, all of them go through the same logic.